# $L^p$-norms for the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, convex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{R}^2$, $1 < p <\infty$ and $\theta\in (0,\infty)$. We consider the mapping
$$
\Gamma : \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow [0,\infty)
$$
defined by $\Gamma(x) = (|x_1|^p + \theta\cdot |x_2|^p)^{1/p}$ with $x = (x_1,x_2)$. My question is whether or not this mapping is strictly convex, that is
$$
\Gamma(\lambda\cdot x + (1-\lambda)\cdot y) < \lambda\cdot\Gamma(x)+(1-\lambda)\cdot\Gamma(y)
$$
for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\lambda\in [0,1]$.

If we remove the term $\theta$ in the definition of $\theta$ is the common $p$-norm or $L^p$-norm, which is strictly convex whenever $p > 1$. ç

I have the intuition that it is true, but I am stuck in that problem.

Comment: What is $ \theta $? Is it just a real number or a positive real number or the theta function from number theory?

Comment: @P.Lawrence I quote " $ \theta \in (0,\infty) $ ".

Answer (score 1):

We can equivalently prove that set $S_\alpha$ defined as $\{x:\Gamma(x)\le \alpha\}$ are convex for $\alpha>0$. Note that this set is symmetric w.r.t. both $x_1$ and $x_2$, which implies that the convexity of $S_\alpha$ is equivalent to that of set $T_\alpha=\{x:x_1\ge 0,x_2\ge 0,x_1^p+\theta x_2^p\le \alpha^p\}$. We can rewrite $T_\alpha$ as
$$
T_\alpha=\left\{x:0\le x_1\le \alpha ,0\le x_2\le \frac{1}{\theta}(\alpha^p-x_1^p)^\frac{1}{p}\right\}.
$$The convexity of $T_\alpha$ then follows from the concavity of $y=\frac{1}{\theta}(\alpha^p-x^p)^\frac{1}{p}$ for $x\in[0,\alpha]$. Since $y\in C^\infty (0,\alpha)$, we have
$$
y''=-\frac{1}{\theta}(p-1)\alpha^p\left(\alpha^px^{-p}-1\right)^{\frac{1}{p}-1}x^{-p-1},
$$we easily conclude that $y$ is concave for $x\in [0,\alpha]$ and the conjecture is proved $\blacksquare$